N-D rotation of numpy vector
I thought this would be easy, but I can't figure it out and google is not helping. I have found straightforward ways to rotate 2D and 3D tensors, but I can't find a way to rotate N-dimensional vectors. In particular I have an N-dimensional vector (numpy array) and I would like to rotate it by theta radiants around an N-dimensional unit vector v.

you could do it with an affine_transform

That's unfortunately not what I want. I would like an N-D version of v @ [[cos(θ), -sin(θ)],[sin(θ), cos(θ)]], affine_transform seems to be modifying an image.

It works on ND arrays, you just need an ND rotation matrix

I realize that, i just cant figure out how to make the matrix

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144153/n-dimensional-rotation-matrix

@fakedrake You have to be careful about what exactly you mean by a "rotation" in N-dimensions. In 3 dimensions, specifying a vector that you want to rotate around and an angle is sufficient to say exactly what you mean, since there is only one 2-dimensional plane that is orthogonal to that vector. Once you go up in dimension, however, there are infinitely many two-dimensional planes perpendicular to v, and it's not clear what exactly a rotation within a higher-dimensional "hyperplane" would entail.

@fakedrake It might help if you explained what exactly you're trying to accomplish using this rotation

@fakedrake If you want, I could put a script together that randomly selects a plane orthogonal to v and then performs the rotation within that plane (as described in Nick's MSE link)

The MSE link is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
